# DIV match height of other div with different aspect ratio responsively with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, match

I'm using JQuery to make DIVs have the same height as their width and update responsively.

I also need to make another DIV (that has a different aspect ratio) keep the same height as the square divs.

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wacdesign/cL8s5La5/)

The black DIV should match the height of the red and white divs, even when resizing the browser window.

```js
function update() {
  $(".match").each(function() {
    var height = $(this).width();
    console.log(height);
    $(this).css('height', height + 'px');
  });
}

update();
$(window).resize(function() {
  update();
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.square {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
}

.oblong {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.color {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="oblong match"></div>
    <div class="square match"></div>
    <div class="square match color"></div>
    <div class="square match"></div>
    <div class="square match color"></div>
    <div class="square match"></div>
    <div class="square match color"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: so what you want for output

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to rezise the div "oblong match" to the same dimensions like the other, when you reszise the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign variable outside of loop, then you'll assign value of the height to the variable in the loop and use it to update the height of element after you exit the loop like this:

```
var height = 0;
function update() {
 $(".match" ).each(function () {
  height = $(this).width();
    console.log(height);
    $(this).css('height',height + 'px'); 
 }); 
 $(".oblong" ).css('height',height + 'px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have applied `max-height:150` to class '.oblong`. Remove it. it shoud work. Please see updated`https://jsfiddle.net/jignesh221290/cL8s5La5/2/`

Comment: The black DIV should match the height of the red and white divs

Answer (score 0):

I have added a wrapper around the boxes and display it as a flexbox. I removed the class `match` from the black box so the height will not be recalculated for it but assigned automatically.

```js
function update() {
  $(".match").each(function() {
    var height = $(this).width();
    console.log(height);
    $(this).css('height', height + 'px');
  });
}

update();
$(window).resize(function() {
  update();
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.toprow {
  display: flex;
}

.square {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.oblong {
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.color {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="toprow">
    <div class="oblong"></div>
    <div class="square match"></div>
    <div class="square match color"></div>
    <div class="square match"></div>
    <div class="square match color"></div>
    <div class="square match"></div>
    <div class="square match color"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```